# Comparar tiempo transcurrido entre fechas en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una `query` en la cual me trae una fecha, lo que quiero realizar es una condición en la cual me diga si han pasado 60 días desde la fecha me lance una alerta, pero no estoy muy orientada sobre como trabajar con diferencias de fechas en `JS`.

Esto es lo que me trae la variable CambioClave: "2018-12-27T14:21:34.000Z"

```
if (data.CambioClave) {
} else {
    sweetAlert
    ({
        title: 'Su contraseña ha expirado ',
        text: 'Por favor cambie su contraseña ',
        icon: 'error',
        buttons: {
            confirm: {
                text: "OK",
                value: true,
                visible: true,
                className: "btn-primary",
                closeModal: true
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: ¿lo que quieres es saber si pasaron 60 días desde la fecha que te indique `CambioClave`?

Comment: Es necesario que te traiga la fecha en la consulta o puedes traerte la diferencia directamente?

Comment: si , quiero saber si desde CambioClave han pasado 60 dias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza new Date() para transformar el String a date y hacer operaciones. Te dejo un código de ejemplo con varios comentarios:

```js
//tu fecha String
let CambioClave="2018-12-27T14:21:34.000Z";
//tu fecha en UTC
let b= new Date(CambioClave);
alert(b);
//El día de hoy
let hoy=new Date();
alert(hoy);
//tu fecha + 60 días
b.setDate(b.getDate() + 60);
alert(b);
//Si tu fecha + 60 es menor que hoy, han pasado más de 60 días
if(b<hoy){
  alert("SI");
}else{
  alert("NO");
}
```

Espero te sirva y consigas adaptarlo a tu código, cualquier cosa me comentas.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias lo consegi adaptar a mi código me sirvió mucho :)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar las operaciones definidas para el tipo Date y adaptar la salida en días:

```js
    var oldDate = new Date("2018-12-27T14:21:34.000Z");
    var today = new Date();
    console.log(DifferenceInDays(oldDate, today));

    function DifferenceInDays(firstDate, secondDate) {
        return Math.round((secondDate-firstDate)/(1000*60*60*24));
    }
```